# A custom node group socket identifier

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

Is it possible to add a socket to a node group with a custom [identifier](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeSocketInterface.html#bpy.types.NodeSocketInterface.identifier)?
So it would be:

```
>>> bpy.data.node_groups["NodeGroup"].inputs["My Socket"].identifier
My Custom Identifier
```

It is necessary because the "mapping" depends on it. I know I can utilize the order of adding, but a custom string is better.

[image]

[A gist for testing.](https://gist.github.com/unwave/8f9a98f0effa2663949cd2e4e134e396)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A script to edit identifiers.](https://gist.github.com/unwave/45d3f2a47c58ddebabe234aab7338333)

It requires [Blender Asset Tracer](https://developer.blender.org/tag/blender_asset_tracer/) and [Python with Tkinter 8.6+](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Blender's Python does not have Tkinter.

[image]

[image]